# Using cookies in Select Query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

So, I have a select query where I am taking the value selected from a drop down list on one page and using that in SELECT queries for others. The issue I am having is that when I navigate from one page to the next, the cookie is not used in the query. If anyone can figure out why, that'd be great.

My code for both pages is below:

Homepage

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductName] FROM [Products]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="ProductName" DataValueField="ProductName">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/infopage.aspx">Information Screen</asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Orders.aspx">Orders Screen</asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Items.aspx">Items Screen</asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Totals.aspx">Total Screen</asp:LinkButton>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

First linked page:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="infopage.aspx.vb" Inherits="infopage" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName], [SupplierID], [CategoryID], [QuantityPerUnit], [UnitPrice], [UnitsInStock], [UnitsOnOrder], [Discontinued], [ReorderLevel] FROM [Products] WHERE [ProductName] = @p1">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:CookieParameter CookieName="product" Name="p1" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="125px">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
                <Fields>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SupplierID" HeaderText="SupplierID" SortExpression="SupplierID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" SortExpression="CategoryID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityPerUnit" HeaderText="QuantityPerUnit" SortExpression="QuantityPerUnit" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="UnitPrice" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsInStock" HeaderText="UnitsInStock" SortExpression="UnitsInStock" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsOnOrder" HeaderText="UnitsOnOrder" SortExpression="UnitsOnOrder" />
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Discontinued" HeaderText="Discontinued" SortExpression="Discontinued" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ReorderLevel" HeaderText="ReorderLevel" SortExpression="ReorderLevel" />
                </Fields>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:DetailsView>
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx">Go back</asp:LinkButton>
            <br />
            <br />

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Code-behind for homepage:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
        Dim product As New HttpCookie("product")
        product.Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
        product.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
        Response.Cookies.Add(product)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you confirmed in the browser (they all have some sort of "developer tools") that the cookie exists and has the value you expect?

Comment: Didn't think to do that. I'll check in just a second @AndrewMorton

Comment: It's not creating the cookie at all, although I'm not sure why it wouldn't. Doesn't the 'Response.Cookies.Add(product) take care of that? @AndrewMorton

Comment: You've got `AutoEventWireup="false"`, so you might need to add an [`OnClientClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx) to the LinkButton.

Comment: What would I fill in there to get the cookie to be created? @AndrewMorton

Comment: Something like `OnClientClick = "LinkButton1_Click"`, so that the `LinkButton1_Click` method is called.

Comment: That still didn't create the cookie. @AndrewMorton

Comment: Debugging hint: you need to determine if `LinkButton_Click` is being called.